# What information goes to app developer when user buys in-app purchase on ios 16?

Tags: ios, privacy, applepay, ios-privacy-settings

What information goes to app developer when user buys in-app purchase (subscription)? Are anything of the following revealed to developers?

- Unique Identifier
- First and last name
- Apple ID
- Email
- Age
- Address

I'm asking from perspective of developing a protection from creating multiple premium accounts by one user.

Comment: Basically none of the data points you mention are shared, no name, email, apple id, age, address (for sort of obvious / relatable privacy reasons): https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/286423/135098

Comment: Please explain why App Store purchase IDs are not sufficient.

Comment: @meaning-matters i'm considering the case when user buys the app multiple times from multiple icloud profiles but with the same credit card and personal info linked to apple ID

Comment: As it's quite unusual that people use two Apple IDs and it would only be good for sales, why do you want to do this?

Comment: What is the problem with user creating multiple premium account if he wants to pay (or loose his money) ?

Comment: @meaning-matters subscription price for my app is relatively cheap and damage from accounts duplication is quite high

Comment: How do you loose money if a user has multiple Apple IDs and purchases multiple times?  Please in your question explain the scenario in detail with explicit reasoning how this damage would occur.